# Taking input from 2 dropdown boxes and going to new page based on both answers

Tags: javascript

I am just learning how to use Javascript and am attempting to create a page that takes the inputs from two drop down boxes and takes the user to a new page based on both inputs. I have figured out how to take the input from just one dropdown box and go to a new page based on that answer, but haven't been able to figure out how go to a new page based on both answers.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newPage()
    {
        var url = document.getElementById("activityMenu").value;
        if(url != "nothing")
        {
            window.location = url;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Looking to travel, but not sure where you want to go? Answer these questions and we'll see if we can give you some suggestions.

```
<p>Please select your travel preferences</p>

<p>Weather Preference </br>
<select name="Weather">
    <option value="Warm">Avg. Temp > 51</option>
    <option value="Cold">Avg. Temp < 51</option>
</select></br>

Trip Activities</br>
<form>
    <select name ="activityMenu" id="activityMenu" accesskey="target">
        <option value="nothing" selected>Select an Activity</option>
        <option value="historicSightseeing.html">Historic Sightseeing</option>
        <option value="Artistic Sightseeing">Artistic Sightseeing</option>
        <option value="Scuba Diving">Scuba Diving</option>
        <option value="Snow Skiing">Snow Skiing</option>
        <option value="Camping">Camping</option>
        <option value="Food Touring">Food Touring</option>
        <option value="Wildlife Watching">Wildlife Watching</option>
    </select></br>
    <input type=button value="Click" onClick="newPage()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your approach, you may branch your form submit callback based on 'weather' dropdown value:

```
if (document.querySelector('select[name="Weather"]').value == 'Warm') {
    //do stuff corresponding to warm weather
}
else if (document.querySelector('select[name="Weather"]').value == 'Cold') {
    //do stuff corresponding to cold weather
}
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler than I expected it to be. I should've thought of that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you're quite welcome, you may mark your question 'answered' if you're satisfied with the answer